# Freepbx - cdr not working

Tags: asterisk

made a new install of asterisk but the CDR isn't working. The online admin panel says the module is installed but the reports are blank. I tried to check the status but it says no such command (cdr status and cdr mysql status). I can't uninstall the module the system says as there are modules that rely on it.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on, seems very odd :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For compilation from source

You have do

```
make menuconfig
```

Select cdr_mysql module in Additional tab

```
make install
```

For rpm install you have install asterisk-mysql package

Comment: Ah thanks, how can I access that after I've installed?

Comment: Hi,
Sorry, figured out how to do it, I had already installed but after entering the asterisk folder I was able to rebuild it with the menuconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Found this. It may help.

http://clients.stabiliservers.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=9

Not sure if you covered all this but that's where I would start. Make sure all configs are correct and applied.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the the latter versions don't need a separate module install so that doesn't really reply, but those configs are correct, but the commands (cdr status etc.), the system says it doesn't recognise them!